# Virtualbox: WARNING! Diff between built and installed module

Tags: virtualbox, kernel-modules, secure-boot

After I signed Virtualbox for secure-boot on Debian I typed `dkms status`.

I've got that message :WARNING! Diff between built and installed module.

Is that because I signed the module ?

Comment: Actually it wasn't because of module signing, also dkms is the latest version, wonder what that message means ?